# GitLab CI pipeline with failed job shows as "waiting for manual action" instead of "failed"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, merge-request

- On [commit 6daa4065](https://gitlab.com/accumulatenetwork/accumulate/-/commit/6daa40659a6b8c7ecae115b38f9904f0c0a07049) there are two jobs, `build binaries` and `build manual binaries`. The first job runs for the main branch and tags. The second branch runs for all other refs but is manual. The status of the commit is "Pipeline #500045869 failed".
- On [commit 6882edeb](https://gitlab.com/accumulatenetwork/accumulate/-/commit/6882edeb2ec769c11d1f77e3905d53ee50505620) there is a single job, `build binaries`, which runs for the main branch and tags but is manual for all other refs. The status of the commit is "Pipeline #500769522 waiting for manual action".

**Both pipelines failed. Why does one say "failed" and the other say "waiting for manual action"?** Nothing depends on `build binaries`.

```yaml
build binaries 6daa4065:
  only: [ develop, tags ]

build manual binaries 6daa4065:
  when: manual
  except: [ develop, tags ]

build binaries 6882edeb:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'develop' || $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != 'develop' && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
    when: manual
```

Comment: Probably because the failed job is in a stage beyond your manual job. Not sure if this is an expected behavior or not.

Comment: On [this commit](https://gitlab.com/accumulatenetwork/accumulate/-/commit/6d277456ee710116c7a41657e5c334c28e11c2f3) the failed job is in an earlier stage and I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like a bug behavior or potentially unintended side-effect of using `needs: []` for all your jobs. Though, nothing in the `needs:` documentation suggests that it should impact the overall pipeline status.